# save file to windows path in python

Tags: python

I would like to save response.txt as an xml file to my windows path : `'S:\nPath_to_save_my_job\nJobsfolder'`

I dont know how to do that.

```
import sys
import requests
import json
import argparse
import pprint
from collections import namedtuple
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
from datetime import datetime

headers = {

    'Content-Type': 'application/json',

}
data = '{"username":"APItest","password":"APItest"}'


response = requests.post('https://MY_CONTROL_MSERVER_/automation-api/session/login', headers=headers, data=data ,verify=False)

response_json = response.json()
pprint.pprint(response_json)
print(response_json['token'])
T = (response_json['token'])


headers = {

    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + T,
}

response = requests.get('https://MY_CONTROL_MSERVER_/folderX/THE_NAME_OF_MY_JOB', headers=headers ,verify=False)


print(response.text)

f = open('response.text', 'w')

sys.stdout = open(response.text + 'w')

save_path = 'S:\nPath_to_save_my_job\nJobsfolder' #(on my windows computer)

name_of_file = raw_input("What is the name of your job: ")

completeName = os.path.join(save_path, name_of_file+".xml")   

completeName.write(toFile)

completeName.close()
```

Comment: Please [format your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361).

Answer (score 3):

The string `'S:\nPath_to_save_my_job\nJobsfolder'` contains a new line character `\n`.

To avoid this, escape the backslashes:

```
'S:\\nPath_to_save_my_job\\nJobsfolder'
```

or use a raw string:

```
r'S:\nPath_to_save_my_job\nJobsfolder'
```